# JQuery - Hide on Scroll Down, Partially Show on Scroll Up, Fully Show when at Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

**Link to JSFiddle with example code; https://jsfiddle.net/m9r510xq/5/**

I am trying to make a header that has the following behavior;

1. Whenever the User scrolls down on the page, the header gets a CSS class (.state-up) that pulls it up and hides completely.
2. Whenever the User scrolls up on the page, the header gets a CSS class (.state-partially) that brings it back down a little, partially showing a bit of the header (some of the top is hidden while some of the bottom is visible).
3. When the User returns to the very top of the page, the header gets a CSS class (.state-down) that returns the header to its normal state, showing it completely.

This is the code I have so far;

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    if (st > 0) {
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            // downscroll code
            $('.a').removeClass('state-down');
            $('.a').removeClass('state-partially');
            $('.a').addClass('state-up')
        } else {
            // uproll code
            $('.a').removeClass('state-down');
            $('.a').removeClass('state-up');
            $('.a').addClass('state-partially')
        }
    } else {
        $('.a').removeClass('state-up');
        $('.a').removeClass('state-partially');
        $('.a').addClass('state-down')
    }
});
```

The logic here is that it checks if the page has been scrolled passed the top of the page. If it has, it then checks for the direction the user is scrolling.

- If they scroll down, it removes any styles associated to up-scrolls and being at the top, and applies only the style associated to down-scrolls.
- If they're scrolling up, it removes any styles associated to down-scrolls and being at the top, and applies only the style associated to up-scrolls.

However, when the page returns to the top, it removes any styles associated to either scroll-direction, and applies only the style associated to being at the top.

I do not have a style applied to the header in the HTML beforehand, I only apply and change out styles via this script.

I was originally using this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/
However, I stepped back from it because I wanted to make sure that the logic I wanted to apply would be possible at a minimal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lastScrollTop` variable gets set to zero every time you scroll the window. You'll need to put that variable outside your scroll event.

Then, at the end of your scroll function, set `lastScrollTop` to be the value of `st` for the current call. That way `lastScrollTop` will be available for the next time the scroll event is called.

Here is a working example:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    if (st > 0) {
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            // downscroll code
            $('.a').removeClass('state-down');
            $('.a').removeClass('state-partially');
            $('.a').addClass('state-up')
        } else {
            // uproll code
            $('.a').removeClass('state-down');
            $('.a').removeClass('state-up');
            $('.a').addClass('state-partially')
        }
    } else {
        $('.a').removeClass('state-up');
        $('.a').removeClass('state-partially');
        $('.a').addClass('state-down')
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
}
.a {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
}
.state-down {
    top: 0px;
}
.state-partially {
    top: -150px;
}
.state-up {
    top: -300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="a">A</div>
</div>
```

And the jsFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/m9r510xq/6/

Comment: This works nicely! However, I'm having some issues when applying it [here](http://www.thegoodmod.com).

When it's using `if (st > 0)`, it is buggy in that when I reach the top, the header doesn't come back into view unless I go down one scroll.

I'm instead using `if (st > navbarHeight)`, which gets its value from `var navbarHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(true);`. This is working better, but because that value is beyond 0, the behavior doesn't kick in until I've scrolled passed the height of `#header`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your site has a lot of CSS and JS, and unfortunately I'm not able to find what JS is causing the problem. You could always try the hacky solution of using an arbitrary number, such as `if (st > 5)`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot that pointing out which file might help; look at **header-scroller.js**. I tried a lower (1, 5) number, but it didn't help much. It's only when it comes closer to the height of `#header` does it work smoothly.

Comment: Went ahead and marked this as the answer. In practice, this is the right way to do it. In my case, it was a bit choppy, but I'm summed that as a result of other factors.